# Extracting Path from URLs in DataFrame

Tags: python, urllib

I'm sure the answer to this is simple - I just can't it for some reason.

I'd like to extract the URL Path from a DataFrame of URLs without using a for loop - as i'll be running this against 1M+ rows and loops are too slow.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
d = {'urls': ['https://www.example.com/ex/1','https://www.example.com/1/ex']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
df['urls'].apply(urlparse)
```

Above is where i'm at, which returns an object of all parts of the URL returned by urllib

The desired end result is a DataFrame like the below:

```
d = {'urls': ['https://www.example.com/ex/1','https://www.example.com/1/ex'], 'url_path': ['/ex/1', '/1/ex']}
```

If anyone knows how to solve this - i'd appreciate the help!

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a dataframe? What you've shown is just a dictionary and looping over a dictionary or strings of a dataframe would be about the same execution time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docstring of `urlparse` clearly says that its result is a named 6-tuple with such fields:
`<scheme>://<netloc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>`

So the solution is two commands:

1. get the tuple at index `2` of `urlparse` result
2. to convert the df into your desired format, pass `orient='list'` arg to the `to_dict` DataFrame method

```
df['paths'] = df['urls'].apply(lambda x: urlparse(x)[2])
df.to_dict(orient='list')
```

Results in

```
{'urls': ['https://www.example.com/ex/1', 'https://www.example.com/1/ex'],
 'paths': ['/ex/1', '/1/ex']}
```